# Getting error for JBOSS 7.2.4 connecting to MQ with ssl error

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq, jboss7.x

Hi in connecting with MQ for Jboss 7.2.4 Getting below error please assist

```
2020-07-31 08:33:48,343 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (Controller Boot Thread) wmq.jmsra.rar: '.
2020-07-31 08:33:48,346 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0215: Failed to resume activity org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent$1@b1f771. To resume normal operation it is recommended that you restart the server.: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYEJB0501: Failed to activate MDB PaymentListener
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.activate(MessageDrivenComponent.java:279)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.access$300(MessageDrivenComponent.java:63)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent$1.resume(MessageDrivenComponent.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.server.suspend.SuspendController.resume(SuspendController.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.finishBoot(ServerService.java:420)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:388)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:134)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:105)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:301)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.acquireConnection(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:279)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:231)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:380)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.rar.EndpointImpl.activate(EndpointImpl.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponent.activate(MessageDrivenComponent.java:277)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM_SSL' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.getConnectOptions(WMQConnection.java:1373)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:343)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.<init>(WMQXAConnection.java:75)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:195)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6254)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:107)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:129)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:203)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
```

Comment: The most likely cause of `MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE` is that you either are not specifying the java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` or that the ciphersuite is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cipher spec defined on your Connection Factory is not compatible with the cipher suites configured on your MQ channel or supported by IBM MQ.

You can check the Connection Factory settings in you application server config. To inspect the channel, you could either use the IBM MQ Console or `runmqsc <YOUR_QM_NAME>` and then `DISPLAY CHANNEL('<YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME>')` to find the value of `SSLCIPH( )`.

[This page in the IBM MQ Knowledge Centre](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm) outlines the cipher naming policies and interoperability. It might also be worth taking a look at the [alias options here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014267_.htm).

If you are using a non-IBM JRE, then check you have set the JVM property `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` for your application server runtime.

There is a simple IBM MQ TLS tutorial [here](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-secure-msgs-tls) which contains a more detailed overview and includes some useful links.